# How to bypass googlemap native app while loading http://maps.google.com in web app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I have a web app and want to show google map app when user clicks on his address. If i redirect the link to http://maps.google.com?q=amritsar#bmb=1, the iphone automatically redirects to iphone google map native app.. And the problem here is there is no back button on google map app , so there is no way to come back to my web app. So i want some way by which maps.google.com?q=amritsar#bmb=1 does not open native web app. but simply opens the url in iframe. I dont want to use google map apis to show the google map because it does not give the ui as that of maps.google.com in iphone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the link for the mobile version of Google Maps (without the maps subdomain) to avoid the redirect to Apple's native Maps app.

Use: http://google.com/maps/m?q=amritsar#bmb=1

Instead of: http://maps.google.com?q=amritsar#bmb=1

Comment: Thanks Dan for reply. Its been very late to give a comment back , but it recently helped me in a proeject now

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<iframe>` to simply include the google map in your web app page. Here's a minimal page that shows the use of the tag.

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>map</h2>
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/?q=amritsar#bmb=1" width="50%" height="50%">
Your browser does not support iframes
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested this on the iPad and it did not redirect to the native app.